# How to get property's display name from a custom attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations

I am trying to create a minimum length validation attribute which will force users to enter the specified minimum amount of characters into a textbox

```
    public sealed class MinimumLengthAttribute : ValidationAttribute
        {
            public int MinLength { get; set; }

            public MinimumLengthAttribute(int minLength)
            {
                MinLength = minLength;
            }

            public override bool IsValid(object value)
            {
                if (value == null)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                string valueAsString = value as string;
                return (valueAsString != null && valueAsString.Length >= MinLength);

  }
    }
```

In the constructor of the MinimumLengthAttribute I would like to set the error message as follows:

ErrorMessage = "{0} must be atleast {1} characters long"

How can I get the property's display name so that I can populate the {0} placeholder?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid using the ErrorMessage Property when assigning the attribute? like: MinimumLength(ErrorMessage = "Email Address must be at least 5 characters long")

Comment: Yes I am trying to avoid setting the error message when assigning the attribute.

Answer (score 7):

The `{0}` placeholder is automatically populated with the value for `[Display(Name="<value>")]` and if the `[Display(Name="")]` attribute doesn't exist then It will take the *Name* of the property.

Answer (score 3):

If your error message has more than one placeholder, they your attribute should also override the [FormatErrorMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.formaterrormessage.aspx) method like so:

```
public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name) {
    return String.Format(ErrorMessageString, name, MinLength);
}
```

And you should call one of the constructor overloads to specfiy your attribute's default error message:

```
public MinimumLengthAttribute()
    : base("{0} must be at least {1} characters long") {
}
```

Comment: Ovveriding the FormatErrorMessage method only works on the server side validation but it doesn't work on the client side. So it would be ideal to set the ErrprMessage property.

Answer (score 1):

You can override

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
```

and use `validationContext.DisplayName`